# one to many relation on appengine with Grails/GORM

Tags: google-app-engine, grails-orm, grails

does anyone know how to handle a "one to many" relationship with Grails/GORM on the google appengine?
I do understand how relationships get handled with Gorm, and there is also a good series of articles about it:

- http://blog.springsource.com/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/
- http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/
- http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/

But I could not find any examples about releastionships within the appengine and **JPA**.

Comment: although I did not solve my original problem yet, I found some great documentation about the appengine datastore: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts - ...better then any docu from google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Gaelyk?  Its a pretty good framework for running groovy on google app engine.  The following link goes over the datasource with groovy on GAE: http://gaelyk.appspot.com/tutorial/app-engine-shortcuts#datastore

Comment: Yes, I do and in fact I gave up on grails and use gaelyk now :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but as far as I've read, you have to use JPA annotations. See here: http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/combining_groovy_grails_mysql_and

Comment: you'r right, using the JPA annotaions is required, but it's not enough for the appengine. as BigTable s not a RDBMS there seems a lot more to be known about relations...